# How to retrieve row data that has null value and one specific value on one column

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to retrieve the row data from table course where program_vss has null and 2 value.

```
return $this->db->get_where('course', array('is_top_course' => 1, 'status' => 'active', 'program_vss'=> null ,  ));
```

any suggestions on how to retrieve data with two conditions

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want a [whereIn()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-wherein) query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array and pass the array:-

**Associative array method:-**

```
$array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);

$this->db->where($array); 

// Produces: WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

Comment: okay, thank you, but how about if there's a two value on title?

Comment: @katbori please edit your question , and post code exactly what you want?.